# Laravel Retrieves Image from S3 with its URL

Tags: amazon-s3, laravel-6

I need to retrieve an image from S3 and post it to Twitter using Laravel. The image is upload with Vapor (Vue js) and path URL stored in the database. Example URL (https://rippleflare-s3-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/7f87e5a4-f157-483e-8dcb-59a735194747). The image is accessible via the browser but when I try to get the image like this

```
Storage::disk('s3')->get($post->media_url)
```

Where the medial url is https://rippleflare-s3-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/7f87e5a4-f157-483e-8dcb-59a735194747 I get the error

Illuminate \ Contracts \ Filesystem \ FileNotFoundException
https://rippleflare-s3-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/7f87e5a4-f157-483e-8dcb-59a735194747

My question, how do I retrieve a file from S3 in Laravel using the file URL (path)

Comment: You don't ask S3 for the URL, you ask for an object in the configured bucket. `7f87e5a4-f157-483e-8dcb-59a735194747` in this case.

Comment: Thanks @deefour Works fine now

Answer (score 0):

you can also define in a model to get your image path like this:

```
 public function getMediaUrlAttribute()
    {
        return Storage::disk('s3')->url($this->media_url);
    }
```

so it will gives your media url